# How to install nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-driver

I have an nvidia card and I'm not surge how to manage drivers on elementary OS.

Is it enough to install the drivers that appear on AppCenter? I installed the 510 drivers before. Should I install the 515 now? Do I need to remove the 510 drivers?

[image]